# Baked image is missing some objects

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, texture-baking, unity

I made a building with many different objects and for baking in Blender internal i joined all those objects (with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>). Then the door animations were gone!

In the baked image the textures of the doors could not be found. All textures were messed up.

Was there any problem in my baking process? Should i not join different meshes together for baking? I want to use it in Unity.

The house before joining all the meshes and doors with different textures and the baked image.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please take a look at the original model, prior to joining all the meshes.

Comment: "*Should i not join different meshes together for baking?*" Probably not blindly, especially if there were animations involved. You will just end up with a needlessly huge texture with lots of repeating parts and blurry quality, instead of smart reuse of tileable patterns

Comment: I have a tendency to create different materials for outside wall and for inside wall of only one wall mesh. I think there was a mistake, I did not select the correct image for each materials in the texture menu. May be that's why the images for the doors (there are 3 doors all total) are messed up with some other image in the baked image.Could you please tell me the correct way of baking in Blender internal where there are many materials for each meshes.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?tbm=vid&q=blender+internal+baking Also there are several addons to simplify the baking process, do a google search